# Is there any possible to connect lampp PMA to mysqld...?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any possible to connect lampp PMA to mysqld which is installed separately in my system...? PMA - PHPMYADMIN (XAMPP)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to configure PMA accordingly

Comment: @Pekka can u give me steps please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly documented both in the phpMyAdmin documentation and in the config file itself.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#cfg_Servers